# SQL Select Query for 365 Days

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to create an SQL query to select percentage utilization for my team members. 
I am looking for a  to daily basis select query to show the utilization when it is greater than 0  and to show '0' when it is null. In order to be able to plot those figures later on as a line chart.

I have written **365** of the following select query and I have combined them together using **"UNION ALL"** method. It is working now, but it is extremely slow!. 
If you have a better idea to produce the daily outputs for the 365 days, that will be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards
Mohamed

Code: 
.........................

```
 SELECT ifnull((    
    SELECT SUM(CAST(pc_loading.value AS INT))
    FROM ticket
    JOIN ticket_custom start_date  ON (ticket.id = start_date.ticket  AND start_date.name  = 'planned_start_date')
    JOIN ticket_custom finish_date ON (ticket.id = finish_date.ticket AND finish_date.name = 'planned_finish_date')
    JOIN ticket_custom pc_loading  ON (ticket.id = pc_loading.ticket  AND pc_loading.name  = 'percentage_loading')
    WHERE UPPER(ticket.owner)='#########'
    AND ticket.type = 'Internal Resource'
    AND DATE(substr(start_date.value, 7, 4)  || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 4, 2)  || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 1, 2))  <= DATE('2020-01-01')
    AND DATE(substr(finish_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 1, 2)) >= DATE('2020-01-01')
    AND status NOT IN ("closed", "suspended")) , 0) UNION ALL

  SELECT ifnull((   
    SELECT SUM(CAST(pc_loading.value AS INT))
    FROM ticket
    JOIN ticket_custom start_date  ON (ticket.id = start_date.ticket  AND start_date.name  = 'planned_start_date')
    JOIN ticket_custom finish_date ON (ticket.id = finish_date.ticket AND finish_date.name = 'planned_finish_date')
    JOIN ticket_custom pc_loading  ON (ticket.id = pc_loading.ticket  AND pc_loading.name  = 'percentage_loading')
    WHERE UPPER(ticket.owner)='#########'
    AND ticket.type = 'Internal Resource'
    AND DATE(substr(start_date.value, 7, 4)  || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 4, 2)  || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 1, 2))  <= DATE('2020-01-02')
    AND DATE(substr(finish_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 1, 2)) >= DATE('2020-01-02')
    AND status NOT IN ("closed", "suspended")) , 0) UNION ALL
```

.......etc
....................................

Comment: You seriously wrote the same query 365 times and `UNION` all of them together? Expected results and some database schema info will be helpful to your question.

Comment: All you need to do is use `GROUP BY` and you can get this into one query. Why are you using `substr` on date comparisons?

Comment: What does your start_date and finish_date columns look like? Please post some sample data. This can get much simpler than what you are currently doing

Comment: start_date & finish_date formats are "YYYY/MM/DD", I had to substring those dates to be able to work on them

Comment: @DragonVale from your concatenations it seems like the dates that you store have this format: `DD/MM/YYYY`

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive `CTE` which returns all the dates of `2020`, cross join it to your query and group by each date:

```
with recursive days as (
  select date('2020-01-01') date 
  union all 
  select date(date, '+1 day') 
  from days
  where strftime('%Y', date, '+1 day') = '2020'
)
SELECT days.date, COALESCE(SUM(CAST(pc_loading.value AS INT)), 0)
FROM days 
CROSS JOIN ticket 
JOIN ticket_custom start_date ON (ticket.id = start_date.ticket AND start_date.name = 'planned_start_date') 
JOIN ticket_custom finish_date ON (ticket.id = finish_date.ticket AND finish_date.name = 'planned_finish_date') 
JOIN ticket_custom pc_loading ON (ticket.id = pc_loading.ticket AND pc_loading.name = 'percentage_loading') 
WHERE UPPER(ticket.owner)='#########' AND ticket.type = 'Internal Resource' 
AND DATE(substr(start_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 1, 2)) <= days.date 
AND DATE(substr(finish_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 1, 2)) >= days.date 
AND status NOT IN ("closed", "suspended")
GROUP BY days.date
```

Also, you would find significant improvement in performance if you stored the dates in a comparable format like `YYYY-MM-DD` since there would be no need for all these rearrangements/concatenations in the `WHERE` clause.
Alternative without the use of the CTE:

```
SELECT days.date, COALESCE(SUM(CAST(pc_loading.value AS INT)), 0)
FROM (
  SELECT '2020-01-01' date UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-02' UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2020-01-03' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-04' UNION ALL
  ............................................................ 
) days 
CROSS JOIN ticket 
JOIN ticket_custom start_date ON (ticket.id = start_date.ticket AND start_date.name = 'planned_start_date') 
JOIN ticket_custom finish_date ON (ticket.id = finish_date.ticket AND finish_date.name = 'planned_finish_date') 
JOIN ticket_custom pc_loading ON (ticket.id = pc_loading.ticket AND pc_loading.name = 'percentage_loading') 
WHERE UPPER(ticket.owner)='#########' AND ticket.type = 'Internal Resource' 
AND DATE(substr(start_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(start_date.value, 1, 2)) <= days.date 
AND DATE(substr(finish_date.value, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(finish_date.value, 1, 2)) >= days.date 
AND status NOT IN ("closed", "suspended")
GROUP BY days.date
```

Comment: It is complaining about the method (recursive days)
 "Report execution failed: near "days": syntax error"

Comment: What is your version of sqlite?

Comment: I think that SQLite supports CTEs since version 3.8.3 So you can't use CTEs unless you upgrade.

Comment: Oh, this is not possible at the moment. do you think is there anyway round it, thanks??

Comment: To simulate the CTE you would have to write a query that would include 365/366 UNION ALL, 1 for each day, like `select '2020-01-01' date union all select '2020-01-02' union all .....` which is not a proper solution, since you already have 365 queries.

Comment: with daily_days as (select date('2020-01-01') date 
  union all 
select date('2020-01-02')
  union all 
select date('2020-01-03')
  union all 
select date('2020-01-04')
  union all 
select date('2020-01-05')
  from days
............

But its is complaining about as now 
"Report execution failed: near "as": syntax error"

Comment: No you can use the WITH clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: It is is half working now, it is much quicker than before tough. I think the "CROSS JOIN ticket" part is not working properly, as I am getting wrong values for multiple dates.

But thanks anyway , you have been really helpful. Much appreciated